# Not able to deploy a helloworld spring-boot app on Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

Getting following error while deploy a simple helloworld `SpringBoot` app on `Cloud Foundry` using `cf push helloworld-api` command.

Note: I am not having a `manifest.yml` file

**Error Log:**

```
Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading binary_buildpack...
   Downloading python_buildpack...
   Downloading go_buildpack...
   Downloading dotnet_core_buildpack...
   Downloading php_buildpack...
   Downloaded binary_buildpack
   Downloading hwc_buildpack...
   Downloaded go_buildpack
   Downloading staticfile_buildpack...
   Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack
   Downloading dotnet_core_buildpack_beta...
   Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack_beta
   Downloading java_buildpack...
   Downloaded hwc_buildpack
   Downloading ruby_buildpack...
   Downloaded staticfile_buildpack
   Downloading nodejs_buildpack...
   Downloaded java_buildpack
   Downloaded python_buildpack
   Downloaded ruby_buildpack
   Downloaded nodejs_buildpack
   Downloaded php_buildpack
   Cell 501d8bad-6db9-4f37-bcbb-bf678aeaa558 creating container for instance ef6baefc-b5e2-4bb4-9c5e-1711b4b8eb5c
   Cell 501d8bad-6db9-4f37-bcbb-bf678aeaa558 successfully created container for instance ef6baefc-b5e2-4bb4-9c5e-1711b4b8eb5c
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (85.1K)
   None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application
   Exit status 222
   Cell 501d8bad-6db9-4f37-bcbb-bf678aeaa558 stopping instance ef6baefc-b5e2-4bb4-9c5e-1711b4b8eb5c
   Cell 501d8bad-6db9-4f37-bcbb-bf678aeaa558 destroying container for instance ef6baefc-b5e2-4bb4-9c5e-1711b4b8eb5c
   Cell 501d8bad-6db9-4f37-bcbb-bf678aeaa558 successfully destroyed container for instance ef6baefc-b5e2-4bb4-9c5e-1711b4b8eb5c
Error staging application: An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack

TIP: Use 'cf buildpacks' to see a list of supported buildpacks.
FAILED
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class HelloworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello World !";
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to add buildpack in your cf, to add java build pack use command `cf push --buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack`

Comment: Don't do what @AmitKBist is suggesting.  You already have a buildpack, we can see that in the output.  Also, you *never* want to point to the master branch of a buildpack.  That can change out from under you and cause all sorts of problems.  If you were to point to a specific buildpack, you could use `java_buildpack` or `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v4.9` or whatever specific version you want to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output from staging is indicating that all of the `detect` scripts ran for all of the installed buildpack, including the Java buildpack, but did not detect that any were able to run your app.

The problem is with your push command, `cf push helloworld-api`.  Since you're deploying a Java app, you need to specify `-p path/to/my.jar`.  You need this so that your compiled application is deployed, not the source code.  Without a path, `cf push` defaults to pushing the current directory which is probably our source code.  The Java buildpack only knows how to deploy compiled apps, it cannot build and deploy your source code.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, you need to give the path for jar correctly. My jar was getting created under target folder, so I had to change the command to

```
cf push springpcf -p target **target**\springpcf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: This was the reason.. Thank you!:)